# MODE aggregation function with redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, aggregate-functions

I have the following tables:

**customers**

```
customer_id name
----------------
1           bob
2           alice
3           tim
```

**purchases**

```
id customer_id item_bought
--------------------------
1  1           hat
2  1           shoes
3  2           glasses
3  2           glasses
4  2           book
5  3           shoes
6  1           hat
```

And I want to following result:

```
customer_name item_bought_most_often
------------------------------------
bob           hat
alice         glasses
tim           shoes
```

I would do this like this (not actually tried, just the idea):

```
SELECT customer.name as customer_name,
  MODE(item_bought) as item_bought_most_ofen
FROM customers
INNER JOIN purchases USING (customer_id)
GROUP_BY customer_id
```

However, the [MODE aggregation function](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Aggregate_Mode) doesn't exist in Redshift.

It seems that [Redshift user defined functions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CREATE_FUNCTION.html) are just regular scalar functions, not aggregations functions. So I don't think I can define it myself.

Any workaround ?

Answer (score 10):

You can mimic `mode()` by using `row_number()`:

```
select name, item_bought
from (select c.name, p.item_bought, count(*) as cnt,
             row_number() over (partition by c.name order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from customers c join
           purchases p
           using (customer_id)
      group by c.name, p.item_bought
     ) cp
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Does Amazon Redshift allow to refer **`cnt`**: `select count(*) as cnt,
             row_number() over (order by cnt desc) as seqnum` at the same level?

Comment: @lad2025 . . . Arrrgh.  Too much Google BigQuery lately.

Comment: I believe this answer is missing `partition by name` to actually yield the result OP is after

Answer (score 8):

You could first `COUNT` each person purchases and then use [`RANK()`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_WF_RANK.html) windowed function:

```
SELECT name AS customer_name, item_bought AS item_bought_most_often
FROM(SELECT name,item_bought,RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY name ORDER BY cnt DESC) rnk
     FROM (SELECT c.name, p.item_bought, COUNT(*) AS cnt
           FROM customers c
           JOIN purchases p
             ON p.customer_id = c.customer_id
           GROUP BY c.name, p.item_bought) AS s1) AS s2
WHERE rnk = 1;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](http://rextester.com/DVRA11614)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔═══════════════╦════════════════════════╗
║ customer_name ║ item_bought_most_often ║
╠═══════════════╬════════════════════════╣
║ alice         ║ glasses                ║
║ bob           ║ hat                    ║
║ tim           ║ shoes                  ║
║ zoe           ║ pencil                 ║
║ zoe           ║ book                   ║
╚═══════════════╩════════════════════════╝
```

Note:

`RANK` will handle multiple most common values.

---

EDIT:

As [Lukas Eder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/521799/lukas-eder) mentioned it could be further simplified:

```
SELECT name AS customer_name, item_bought AS  item_bought_most_often
FROM(SELECT name,item_bought,
            RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY name ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) rnk
     FROM customers c
     JOIN purchases p
       ON p.customer_id = c.customer_id
     GROUP BY c.name, p.item_bought)  AS s2
WHERE rnk = 1;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0ca0af4514ae8e80cfd823a199d38514)**

Comment: I was doing something similar. I was really hoping for an aggregation function like `FIRST(my_column), MODE(my_column)`, or the ability to define it. But it doesn't exist. Another possibility would be something like `SPLIT_PART(LISTAGG(id, ','),',',1)`. or `udf_mode(LISTAGG, id, ',')`. udf_mode being a user defined function that calculates the mode based on string of values separated by a comma. But those are all hacky.

Comment: @pinouchon Based of [doc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/user-defined-functions.html) *`You can create a custom user-defined >>scalar<< function (UDF)`*. I do not see user-defined aggregate functions doc like in Postgresql [CREATE AGGREGATE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createaggregate.html) Idea with using `LISTAGG` and then using udf_mode could work.

Comment: There's no need for the second level derived table, you can `ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC` directly

Comment: @LukasEder Thank you for your comment. I have extended the answer to include that version too.